# this mughal jade cup, it's "瓜瓣瓢" or "瓜辨瓢"?

Tags: traditional-characters, character-identification, poetry

this week, the christie's have an auction of this jade cup:

[image]

i suspected this one is the object of emperor 乾隆's poem 痕都斯坦玉羊頭瓜辨瓢歌

[image]

my question is:

the poem title is 玉羊頭瓜**辨**瓢

is it an typo of 瓣?

cause, in the poem, the 5th verse mentioned 瓜分數**瓣**

> 鹿臺嘉産来遐陬
>
> 彼中良工細雕鎪
>
> 式異漢盃及商卣
>
> 瓢飲一具琢羙球
>
> 瓜分數瓣花葉浮
>
> 曲柄廻顧為羊頭
>
> 匪夷所思用意周
>
> 其脂非逺其性柔
>
> 東陵闗内伊誰候

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it should be 瓜瓣瓢.

- 瓜瓣瓢 probably means a 瓢 made from 瓜瓣. In contrast, 瓜辨 is not a word (AFAIK).
- See a printed version of 清・金士松《喬羽書巢詩集》 (https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=en&file=105725&page=51). Since your screenshot looks like it's from a handwritten version of 《御製詩四集》, I suspect that it's a handwriting error. Well, printing is less likely to introduce errors :)

  [image]

Comment: semantically, it should be "瓜瓣", "瓜辨" does not make any sense. well, i'm now guessing who made the typo? the emperor himself, then the copy-writer didn't dare to rectify it. or the copy-writer made it, and proof-readers didn't discover it?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 Well, 金士松《喬羽書巢詩集》 says 瓜瓣瓢, so I'm guessing that even if the Emperor wrote it wrongly, someone still "dared" to rectify it. However, I'm thinking that the copy-writer was the one who made the mistake. Maybe some museum still has the original copy of the fabric/paper that the poem was written on...

Comment: btw, th poem is in the  四庫全書　集部　御製詩四集　卷六十四, page 28: https://archive.org/details/06054259.cn/page/n28

Comment: how dare was mr 金 :)